# How to remove CC and BCC from Recipients address : JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, message

I am able to add CC,BCC and TO successfully to message or Mimemessage, But my requirement is I need to send the constructed email to some third party for backup purpose. 
I Tried this:

```
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, null);
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, "");
```

Please help!!!

Comment: How it (jakarta mail) responds when all to, cc & bcc are empty. Java mail sender doesn't throw any error, also it's not there in sent mail folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setRecipients](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html#setRecipients-javax.mail.Message.RecipientType-javax.mail.Address:A-) instead of setRecipient, with a null address.

Comment: It works fine for me using `message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, (Address[])null);`  If it's still not working for you, post a sample program showing the problem and the stack trace from the NullPointerException.  Also, what version of JavaMail are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I got an NPE when trying to pass a null for the 2nd arg, but using an empty array did the trick for me:

```
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, new Address[]{});
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new Address[]{});
```